# Place a photo to the right of the address

Tags: header-footer, cv, resume

I am trying to place a photo in my CV besides my address. Now I use the code:

```
       % LaTeX resume using res.cls
    \documentclass{res} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.95in}  % Start text higher on the page 
    \setlength{\textheight}{10.2in}  % increase textheight to fit more on a page
    \setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}     % space between header and text
    \setlength{\headheight}{12pt}   % make room for header
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}  % use fancyhdr package to get 2-line header
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % suppress line drawn by default by fancyhdr
    \pagestyle{fancy} % set pagestyle for the document



    \begin{document} 
    \name{My Name}
    \address{ Adress 123\\   222 22 City \\   123 123 \\  }
    \begin{flushright}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3.5cm]{photo.jpg} %Choose a photo 
    \end{flushright}

    \begin{resume}

     %Some text

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Now the photo appears above the next, but I would like *the photo to be beside my address information*. I am really a latex beginner so any suggestions are much appreciated!

Best Regards

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:) What is `res.cls`?

Comment: Without your class file it is hard to answer, but I suspect that putting the image inside your address is the easiest answer: `\address{ Adress 123\\   222 22 City \\   123 123 \\ \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3.5cm]{photo.jpg}`. Of course you will probably have to adjust it's placement to your tastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tabular`s like this

```
\address{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
Address 123\\   
222 22 City 
\\   123 123 
\end{tabular}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo}
\end{tabular}
}
```

[image]

If you want to flush the photo, use two `\address` fields

```
\address{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
Address 123\\
222 22 City
\\   123 123
\end{tabular}
}
\address{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo}
\end{tabular}
}
```

[image]

But the `res` class is really old (Dating to 2000 AD). These days you have modern calsses like `moderncv`. Use them instead.

Comment: @user1665355 You are welcome :)

Comment: I will also use the handsome photo you added, in my CV :)